# How can I check whether hh:mm < hh:mm

Tags: java, string, time

Let's suppose we have

```
"12:00"
```

and

```
"14:30"
```

How can I check whether `12:00 < 14:30`?

Comment: These are `LocalTime`s. You should check their documentation to see if you can compare them.

Comment: Depends. In your estimation, is 23:59 before or after 0:00?

Comment: What you mean *How can I check whether 12:00 < 14:30?* - you want to have a boolean variable to store whether a < b or a > b?

Comment: How about `"12:00".compareTo("14:30") < 0`?

Answer (score 4):

### You can use [LocalTime#isAfter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-) or [`LocalTime#isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-)

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("12:00");
        LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse("14:00");

        // If time1 is after time2
        System.out.println(time1.isAfter(time2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this format zero-fills leading zeros (e.g., eight and three minutes AM would be represented as "08:03"), a lexicographical comparison will do the trick. Luckily, `String`s in Java are [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```java
String a = "12:00";
String b = "14:30";

int cmp = a.compareTo(b);
if (cmp < 0) {
    System.out.println("a is earlier");
} else if (cmp == 0) {
    System.out.println("a and b are equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("b is earlier");
}
```

Comment: Since OP showed format as `hh:mm`, i.e. 2-digit hour and minute values, and examples use 24-hour format, there is not much assuming in that assumption. 

Answer (score 2):

You can either `split()` your strings by ":" and compare hours with hours, and if needed minutes with minutes. Or you can convert those strings to objects of the relevant classes of the [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and operate with the methods those classes offer, like `LocalTime.isAfter()` or `LocalTime.isBefore()`.